# Exponential modular in mips assembly

Tags: assembly, mips, modular

I have to make a modular exponential of a^{b}(mod c), the problem is that the values ​​of a and b can be very large, at most 65534 and less than 1

The code is already approved in most test cases, but for values ​​close to 60k it doesn't work.
how can I make this exponential 65534^{65534} without having problems in mips?

Comment: It is important that you calculate `mod c` on intermediate results. Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation for the general idea. For mips-specific questions, you need to show some code.

Comment: Fortunately (or by design), the square of 65534 (the largest intermediate value that you could encounter, before reducing it) still fits in an (unsigned) 32bit integer, so it won't be very complicated.